# Spring Boot Logging override Colours

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j2

I wish to use different colours to distinguish between INFO, DEBUG and TRACE in Spring Ansi Coloured Logs, as they are currently all set to Green (see table below)

From the docs here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-logging-color-coded-output

> Color coding is configured by using the `%clr` conversion word. In its simplest form, the converter colors the output according to the log level, as shown in the following example:
>
> `%clr(%5p)`
> The following table describes the mapping of log levels to colors:

| Level | Color |
| --- | --- |
| FATAL | Red |
| ERROR | Red |
| WARN | Yellow |
| INFO | Green |
| DEBUG | Green |
| TRACE | Green |

It would appear I need to override the `%clr` conversion word, but I cannot find anything in the docs about that.

If it makes a difference I am using log4j2, and wish to build this into the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any conventional/documented way to override colors at a level scope.  For example : [ColorConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/ColorConverter.java) for log4j2 doesn't like to be opened for that kind of options.
You could  try to define your Log42 color plugin implementation, that is a plugin implementation annotating with that log4j2 `Plugin` annotation :

```
@Plugin(name = "color", category = PatternConverter.CATEGORY)
```

But not sure that it works or works reliably since Spring defines already one for that.
For the record here is the [ColorConverter source code for logback.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/ColorConverter.java)

By the way, if it is enough, you could define a pattern by starting from the `CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN` defined [in the Spring Boot source code for log4j2:](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2.xml)

```
<Property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN">%clr{%d{${sys:LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN}}}{faint} %clr{${sys:LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN}} %clr{%pid}{magenta} %clr{---}{faint} %clr{[%15.15t]}{faint} %clr{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} %clr{:}{faint} %m%n${sys:LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD}</Property>
```

Comment: Not sure why the log4j2 ColorConverter is final and the logback one isn't, but have created a new implementation along the lines of Springs own, and it works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: That is good but not sure about reliability over the time. I thought (maybe wrong) that you had broadly 50% of chance that it works (as Spring could select any of log4j2 plugin declaring the color plugin : `@Plugin(name = "color", category = PatternConverter.CATEGORY)`. That is yours and theirs.  Did you add anything to force the use of your plugin rather than theirs ?

Comment: Yes, I added the new implementation with a different plugin name `sclr` and tweaked the CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN to use it. I would have preferred to reuse the existing class in someway but as most things were private or not made for extending there wasn't much to re-use..

Answer (score 2):

First, the %clr defined is a logback conversion rule and is the one with the color logic.
This conversion rule is defined in the spring class [DefaultLogbackConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/DefaultLogbackConfiguration.java).

There we can see that spring adds the [ColorConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/ColorConverter.java) with the clr conversionWord in the logback configurator.

From this exploration, my conclusion is that you have to create your own logback.xml file (it disable spring default configuration, according to the documentation). With this file in place, you can add your own conversion rule like this:

```
<conversionRule conversionWord="nanos" 
              converterClass="chapters.layouts.MySampleConverter" />
```

After that you should change the property logging.pattern.console using your conversionWord created above, instead of %clr.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GrepConsole plugin (Idea) for it.
See more [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console)

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer, however I'm looking for something that will work at the CLI level. ie. `java -jar xxxx.jar`